# Bootstrap Multiselect (David Stutzs) options to show up ward direction

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a multiselect drop down converted to [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) version and placed at the end of page as required by application page.

Now, clicking on this multiselect is causing page vertical scroll bar to appear as it displays options downwards. Is there a way to display options upwards (may be also automatically based on space available on page)? **If space is available then display down, otherwise display up Automatically.**

I am using the following configuration for multiselect -

```
MultiSelect.setMultiSelect = function MultiSelect$setMultiSelect(input,includeSelectAllOption) {
    var inputField = jQuery('#' + input);
    try
    {
        inputField
                .multiselect({
                    maxHeight : 400,
                    includeSelectAllOption : includeSelectAllOption,
                    enableFiltering : false,
                    buttonWidth : '100%',
                    dropRight : true
                    }
                });
    } catch (ex)
    {}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In documentation you can see method `dropup`

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-dropUp

You can define it in options like this:

```
MultiSelect.setMultiSelect = function MultiSelect$setMultiSelect(input,includeSelectAllOption) {
    var inputField = jQuery('#' + input);
    try
    {
        inputField
                .multiselect({
                    maxHeight : 400,
                    includeSelectAllOption : includeSelectAllOption,
                    enableFiltering : false,
                    buttonWidth : '100%',
                    dropUp : true
                    }
                });
    } catch (ex)
    {}
}
```

Just remember `maxheight` needs to be set

Comment: Thq @JTC. I am wondering if it can be done automatically based on screen space (If there is a space downwards, else upwards). I will mark your answer as accepted in few

Comment: Well in your case, you could fiddle with multiselect code and set `dropUp` true as default, but I would not recommend this, also as stated on documentation `dropup` option can sometimes fail